# Deadlocks, Mutexes and Signal,Slots in Qt

Tags: qt, mutex, deadlock

I am developing an application that uses QSerialPort to receive data via uart. In this application I use a log function that writes to a file. Before writing to the file the application locks a mutex and after writing to the file it unlocks the mutex. Between mutex lock and unlock I am not calling the log function again.

Of course the data coming from serial port arrives asynchronously and it triggers a signal and a slot where the data is processed. In this function where the data is processed I am calling the log function again.

I am not using multithreading in my application, as far as I know the slots are called in the same thread.

The question is: can the single thread deadlock itself when the data from QSerialPort arrives exactly after the mutex in the log function was locked ? (This would mean a double lock of the same mutex - assume we do not use a recursive mutex)

Is there a good source of knowledge about such a topic ?

Answer (score 1):

If your serial port gets data exactly after the mutex locked it will not execute immediatly (because this is not interruption) but it wait when `QEventLoop` will execute a receiving data slot (in global event loop). You can execute all events manually with `qApp->processEvents()` so try to avoid it inside lock/unlock block.

If you use explicit calling of log function in single thread you will not have a deadlock (I think). But be carefull with writing a log via `qDebug()` macro with reimplementing `qInstallMessageHandler` because you can forget and use `qDebug()` inside mutex lock/unlock block. Then you will have a deadlock.

Also it could be some troubles with callback functions inside your lock/unlock block. So be carefull with callbacks too.